# Proving local non-satiation in arbitrary metric space

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-theory, general-equilibrium

I have a pure exchange economy where every consumption set $X_i$ is non-empty and convex and every preference relation $\succeq_{i}$ is strictly convex. I am asked to show that preferences are locally non-satiated at any consumption bundle different from the single ‘satiation point’ (i.e. the bundle which is strictly preferred to all other bundles in the consumption set; I have already proved that the satiation point, $x^*$, is unique).

So far I have:

Consider an arbitrary $x_{i}\in X_{i}$. Consider $\hat{x}:=\phi x_i+(1-\phi)x^*$, $\phi\in(0,1)$. Consider an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$. Now, choose $\phi$ such that the distance between $\hat{x}$ and $x_{i}$ is less than $\epsilon$. That is, $\phi\in(0,1)$ such that $\phi x_i+(1-\phi)x^*<\epsilon$. I get that $\phi<\frac{\epsilon+x_{i}-x^{*}}{x_{i}-x^{*}}$.  We must have that $\phi\in(0, \min\{1, \frac{\epsilon+x_{i}-x^{*}}{x_{i}-x^{*}}\})$. Also, note that, by strict convexity, $\hat{x}\succ x_{i}$.

Beyond this point I am stuck. Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How do you define strict convexity? And where do the arbitrary metric spaces come in?

Comment: Strict convexity: if two (distinct) bundles are weakly preferred to some third bundle, then any linear combination of those two bundles, with weights in $(0,1)$, is strictly preferred to the third.

Comment: Arbitrary metric spaces come in because no assumption is being made as to the type of metric that $X$ is. i.e. we have not said that $X =\mathbb{R}^{N}_{+}$

Comment: Convex combinations do not make sense in general metric spaces. What you need is a metric on a vector space such that the vector operations are continuous. The expression $\phi x_i+(1-\phi)x^*<\epsilon$ does not really make sense.

Answer (score 6):

First, you need a vector space in order for convex combinations to be well-defined. However, not every metric on a vector space works. Indeed, under the [discrete metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space), the result will trivially fail unless space consists of the point $0$ alone. What works is a metric on the vector space such that the vector operations of addition and scalar multiplication are continuous. Actually, no metric is needed and the result holds any [topological vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space). However, I doubt this is the level of generality the problem was posed at.

Anyways, here is the argument: Let $x$ be any point in $X_i$ that is not a global satiation point (there is not necessarily a unique satiation point because there might be no satiation point at all). Let $x^*$ be any point such that $x^*\succ_i x$. Let $x_n=(n-1)/n\, x+1/n\, x^*$. By strict convexity, $x_n\succ_i x$ for $n\ge 1$. By the continuity of the vector operations, $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=x$. Therefore, every neighborhood or ball around $x$ will contain a point of the form $x_n,$ which is strictly better. Therefore, $\succeq_i$ is locally non-satiated.

Comment: Thank you. But how does your conclusion that ‘every neighbourhood or ball around x will contain a point of the form x_n, which is strictly better (than x)’, follow from the fact that x_n converges to x?

Comment: That is, how do we know that the distance between x_n and x is less than some epsilon>0?

Comment: @Charles: Because this is part of the definition of $x_n$ converging to $x$.

Comment: @VARulle Thank you. I have attempted an answer below for the case in which we assume X is the positive real quadrant

Comment: @Charles, this is not wrong, but unnecessarily complicated. By construction of $x_n$ the distance $||x_n-x||$ is $(1/n)\,||x-x^*||$, so it should be clear that for any $\epsilon>0$ we can find an $n$ with $||x_n-x||<\epsilon$. Any $n>||x-x^*||/\epsilon$ will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer for if we assume $X=\mathbb{R}^{2}_{+}$.

Consider some $x:=(x_1, x_2) \in X$, distinct from the satiation point ($x^{*}:=(x_1^{*}, x_2^{*})$). Consider some $\epsilon>0$. By strict convexity, $x':=\bigg(\phi x_1+(1-\phi)x_1^{*}, \phi x_2+(1-\phi)x_2^{*}\bigg)\succ (x_1, x_2)  $ for all $\phi\in (0,1).$ Next, note that $||x'-x||$ is given by $\sqrt{(x'_1-x_1)^2+(x_2'-x_2)^2}=\sqrt{(\phi x_1+(1-\phi)x_1^{*}-x_1)^2+(\phi x_2+(1-\phi)x_2^{*}-x_2)^2}$. Choose $\phi$ such that $(\phi x_1+(1-\phi)x_1^{*}-x_1)\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $(\phi x_2+(1-\phi)x_2^{*}-x_2)\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ (WLOG, we assume that $x_1^*>x_1$ and $x_2^*>x_2$, so that $(\phi x_1+(1-\phi)x_1^{*}-x_1)$ and $(\phi x_2+(1-\phi)x_2^{*}-x_2)$ are strictly positive). This requires that $\phi \leq \frac{\frac{\epsilon}{2}+x_1-x_1^{*}}{x_1-x_1^{*}}$ and $\phi \leq \frac{\frac{\epsilon}{2}+x_2-x_2^{*}}{x_2-x_2^{*}}$, equivalent, respectively, to  $1-\frac{\epsilon}{2(x_1^*-x_1)}$ and $1-\frac{\epsilon}{2(x_2^*-x_2)}$. Note then that $||x'-x||\leq \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}<\epsilon.$

Thus, given any $x\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$, we can find some $x'$, as defined above, with $\phi\in\bigg(0, \min\bigg\{1, 1-\frac{\epsilon}{2(x_1^*-x_1)},1-\frac{\epsilon}{2(x_2^*-x_2)} \bigg\}\bigg)—$so that $x'\in B_\epsilon(x)—$and such that $x'\succ x$.